# Why any composite number other that $4$ should not be element of $C$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $A$ denote the set of all prime numbers, $B$ the set of all prime numbers and the number $4$, and let $C$ denote the set of positive integers $k$, for which $$\dfrac{(k-1)!}{k}$$ is *not* an integer. Then, $C=B$.

I can see that every prime should be an element of $C$ as if $k$ is prime, then none of $1,\dots,k-1$ is divisible by $k$. Also $4$ must be there, as $1\times2\times3$ is not divisible by $4$. But I can't understand why there is no other composite number that is fatal as $4$.

Why any composite number other that $4$ should not be element of $C$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a composite number $k$ factors into two distinct smaller factors, then both will appear in $(k-1)!$ and thus cancel the $k$. Thus, we only need to consider squares of primes. If $k=p^2$, then if $k>2p$, then $(k-1)!$ will have $p$ and $2p$ as factors, and will thus cancel the $k$. Thus, the only nonprime $k$ that works is such that $p^2\le 2p$, and $2$ is the only such prime, giving $k=4$.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints. First, suppose $k$ is composite -- then it has a smallest prime $p$ that divides it, with $k = pq$ for some integer $q$.

If $q \neq p$, can you prove that $(k-1)!$ is divisible by $k$?

This leaves only the case where $k=p^2$ is the square of a prime. $k$ will divide $(k-1)!$ if at least two multiples of $p$ appear in the list of numbers $p^2-1, p^2-2, \ldots, 2, 1.$ Can you think of why at least one multiple of $p$ must always appear? When does a second appear?

Finally, what you're asking is essentially an important theorem in elementary number theorem called Wilson's Theorem. You can find all of the above spelled out by searching for this theorem, but I urge you to try to figure the problem out yourself first.